# Почему шрифт не подключился?

Tags: css

Хотел подключить шрифт INTER нашел файл в интернете єтого щрифта, и попытался подключить но нечего не изменилось в чем проблема?

```html
<style type="text/css">
    
@font-face {
font-family: "Inter"; 
src: url("https://bestfonts.pro/fonts_files/5d7a434b2f8879a3f9baf441/files/Inter-ThinBETA.woff") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal; 
} 
    
    body {
        font-family: "Inter"; 

    }
</style>
<body>
текст
 </body>
```

Comment: в body обязательно нужно указывать запасной шрифт `sans-serif`

Comment: Все ошибки в консоли. Этот сайт не позволяет брать с него шрифты. И вообще Inter есть на google fonts.
З,Ы, а ещё вы woff файл почему-то объявили truetype-ом

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter
https://rsms.me/inter/#usage